# Increment IP address by 1 depending on value of subnet (on different column)

Tags: pandas, addition, ip-address

I have this DF, composed of [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) type objects.

```
        subnet
0  10.204.26.0
1  10.204.26.0
2  10.204.26.0
3  10.204.30.0
4  10.204.30.0
5  10.204.30.0
6  10.204.30.0
7  10.204.30.0
8  10.204.30.0
9  10.204.30.0
```

I want to create a new column, say `df['ip']` which will increment on the `subnet` (and/or previous `row`) to get a different address on each different row, but taking into account that the subnets do differ.

If the subnet is only one, the problem is easily solved by doing `df['ip'] = df.index + df[subnet] + 1`. That would produce something like this:

```
        subred            ip
0  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.1
1  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.2
2  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.3
```

But since the subnets are likely to be more than one, then the expected result would be:

```
        subred            ip
0  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.1
1  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.2
2  10.204.26.0   10.204.26.3
3  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.1
4  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.2
5  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.3
6  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.4
7  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.5
8  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.6
9  10.204.30.0   10.204.30.7
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
df['ip']= df['subnet'].str[:10]+ (df.groupby('subnet').cumcount()+1).astype(str)
df
```

**output**

```
         subnet     ip
0   10.204.26.0     10.204.26.1
1   10.204.26.0     10.204.26.2
2   10.204.26.0     10.204.26.3
3   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.1
4   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.2
5   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.3
6   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.4
7   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.5
8   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.6
9   10.204.30.0     10.204.30.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work, since `df['subnet'].str[:10]` returns a series of `NaN`  because `df['subnet']` is not a string, but an `ipaddress` object ... may be if a convert that into string might work ...

Comment: I was going to say that you can convert the IP address into string but you figured it yourself :-) Glad to be of help.

Comment: Yes, converting it into a string, does work. I still need to figure out something else. Because the `str[:10]` works if the IP address keep the `shape` in terms of octets. But it won't work if, for example, one the subnets would be `192.168.254.0` ... in any case, thanks for the idea!

Comment: What happened? converting the IP address into string did not work?

Comment: based on your idea, I found a solution that works with out converting the `subnet` into a string. `df['subred'] + (df.groupby('subred').cumcount()+1)` ... this is the best answer, I believe ...

Comment: If can try this if you want as well `df['ip']= df['subnet'].str.rsplit('.',1).str[0]+ '.'+(df.groupby('subnet').cumcount()+1).astype(str)` . IP adrress may have to be converted to text here. I got the 'subnet' column as text hence working with it as text.